# Знаки препинания во внутреннем монологе персонажа

Tags: пунктуация, авторская-пунктуация

У А. и Б. Стругацких довольно часто в текстах внутренний монолог персонажа выглядит следующим образом:

"Он несколько раз мысленно проделал сборку, а когда раскрыл глаза, передатчика не было. И ничего не было. Робинзон, подумал он с некоторым даже интересом. Максим Крузое. Надо же, ничего у меня нет. Шорты без карманов и кеды. Но зато остров у меня – обитаемый… А раз остров обитаемый, значит, всегда остается надежда на примитивный нуль-передатчик. Он старательно думал о нуль-передатчике, но у него плохо получалось."

Или: "Он поглядел вслед чудовищу и вдруг заметил, что поперечная дорога – не просто дорога, а просека, узкая щель в лесу: деревья не закрывали над нею неба, как над шоссе. Может, догнать его? – подумал он. Остановить, погасить котел… Он прислушался. В лесу стоял шум и треск..."

Я нарочно копирую текст со словами авторов и внутренним монологом персонажа, потому что все справочники по пунктуации требуют в таких случаях заключить внутренний монолог в кавычки.

Как получилось, что у Стругацких это правило не соблюдается? Понимаю про авторскую стилистику и замысел, но корректура советских издательств вряд ли была так лояльна. Значит, существует какое-то правило, позволяющее писать таким образом? Как же звучит это правило, и где можно найти его описание?

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, что это некорректное оформление. Для передачи внутреннего монолога надо использовать **несобственно-прямую речь,** а она оформляется немного по-другому (там нет местоимений, отнесенных к первому лицу), например:

Он несколько раз мысленно проделал сборку, а когда раскрыл глаза, передатчика не было. И ничего не было. Робинзон, подумал он с некоторым даже интересом, Максим Крузое.  Надо же, ничего **у него** нет.  Шорты без карманов и кеды. Но зато остров  – обитаемый… А раз остров обитаемый, значит, всегда остается надежда на примитивный нуль-передатчик. Он старательно думал о нуль-передатчике, но у него плохо получалось.

Он поглядел вслед чудовищу и вдруг заметил, что поперечная дорога – не просто дорога, а просека, узкая щель в лесу: деревья не закрывали над нею неба, как над шоссе. **Может, догнать его?**   Остановить, погасить котел… Он прислушался. В лесу стоял шум и треск..."

**О несобственно-прямой речи**

Несобственно-прямая речь - удивительный художественный прием. Как говорят, это изобретение Пушкина. Мы видим ПЛАВНЫЙ переход от автора-рассказчика к автору-герою, который погружается в его внутренний мир, смотрит на окружающую действительность его глазами. Это Достоевский (для примера): "Но вот его комната. Ничего и никого, никто не заглядывал. Даже Настасья не притрагивалась. Но, Господи! Как мог он оставить давеча все эти вещи в этой дыре? Он бросился в угол, запустил руку под обои и стал вытаскивать вещи и нагружать ими карманы."

А это материал о несобственно-прямой речи https://studfiles.net/preview/1101520/page:21/

Answer (score 0):

Случаи таких "перескоков" с авторской на собственную речь встречаются в экспериментальной литературе, где есть задача размыть грань между героем и рассказчиком. Но там нет ремарок "подумал он". Например, такое есть в "Улиссе"
Иногда правильная пунктуация "исчезает" при передаче прямой речи. Например, в быличках часто можно встретить ремарку "говорю" между запятыми, но без кавычек и длинных тире.Вероятно, это нужно, чтобы отразить непрерывность мысли и манеру говорить рассказчика.
Также пунктуация прямой речи местами не проставляется в Библии. Возможно, по лени издателей.
В приведённом отрывке причин для такого написания нет. Налицо нарушение правил пунктуации. Искать этому обоснования не вижу. Есть правила, а чтобы их нарушать, нужна достойная цель.

Comment: @Sharon Вы что-то напутали. Я не задавал вопрос, а отвечал на него. Это Вы в своём ответе углубились в одну лишь несобственно прямую речь. Я тут не при чём.

Comment: Извините, если напутала. Комментарий удален (перенесен в ответ). Но размытость грани между рассказчиком и автором, о которой Вы упоминаете, - это и есть несобственно-прямая речь. Используется в качестве художественного приема еще со времен Пушкина.

Comment: @Sharon я бы не говорил, что всё исчерпывается только этим приёмом. В своём ответе Вы заострили внимание на ПЛАВНОМ переходе от речи автора к речи персонажа. В случаях, о которых написал я, это не всегда так. Например, в "Улиссе". Поэтому я предпочёл бы воздержаться от терминов.

Comment: Извините еще раз, мне жаль, что наши мнения не совпадают. Важен вывод: мне нравится такое оформление, его надо только немного подправить, чтобы оно соответствовало  существующим правилам (а они существуют). Вы же такое оформление не одобряете, считаете его в принципе неправильным. Конечно же, я уважаю Ваше мнение, поэтому и перенесла комментарий в ответ.

Comment: @Sharon с Вами приятно общаться. Спасибо.